# Negative percent below 100%

Tags: percentages

Maybe this is a dumb question, but is it valid to have a negative percent below -100% when comparing two quantities?

I'm evaluating the Net Present Value of an investing project affected by many external variables. The expected NPV of the project is 122961$. When affected by external varialbes, the worst case scenario makes the NPV equal to -11128, which means a deviation of -109%. Does this have a valid meaning?

Comment: When talking about percentages, it must be made perfectly clear "*percentages* **of what**."  When we talk about milk for example... we might have "2% milk" vs "Skim milk."  Is the 2% in "2% milk" that only 2% of the total liquid in it is milk., that it has only 2% the usual amount of fat?  That it has 2% the recommended daily intake of fat per serving?  That 2% of the total volume *is* fat?  If you just say a percent by itself it is almost meaningless.  If you clarify what the percentage is *of* however, then it should be clear that they can be any value depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense.

You are saying that the worst-case NPV is $109\%$ less than the expected NPV.

---

However, it just sounds a little awkward, but the point comes through.

It sounds normal to say "stocks increased $200\%$" to represent stocks tripling in value, but since $-100\%$ means $0$, it's not common to use such percentages.